# Finding the most occuring character in an array of char

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm trying to find the most occurring character in this array with the following algorithm:

```
char a[]={"aaaadddddaa"};
int max=0;
int count=0;
char maxCharcter;
for(char q='a';q<='z';q++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==q)
            count++;
    }

    if(count>max)
    {
        max=count;
        maxCharcter=q;
    }
}

cout<<max<<endl;
cout<<maxCharcter<<endl;
```

The output should have been `max=6 maxCharcter=a`, but I get `max=11 maxCharcter=d`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that while this works (once corrected), it’s very inefficient. There’s a much more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Some combination of `std::unique` and `std::count` would do you better than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

`count` should be initialized inside your first for loop

```
for(char q='a';q<='z';q++) {
   count = 0;
   //continue code here
}
```

Comment: @XNA Instead of thanking, upvote the answer and possibly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably you only "reset" count once, not for every character.

```
int count=0;
char maxCharcter;
for(char q='a';q<='z';q++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a);i++)
```

Probably should be

```
char maxCharcter;
for(char q='a';q<='z';q++)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(a);i++)
```

Other than that, you could speed up the whole thing by just going through the string once, using another array to count the occurrences of each char...